# Poisson distribution

Tags: probability

The number of particles emitted by a radio-active source is recorded for a period
of $10$ hours; a total of $1800$ counts is registered. During how many one-minute
intervals do we expect to have observed respectively $0$, $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, and $5$ particle
counts?

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint 1:**

The probability of $k$ events happening in an interval of time $t$ is
$$
P(k)=\frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda t}
$$
where $\lambda$ is the event rate ($1800/600$ events per minute).

**Hint 2:**

The expected number of occurrences is the probability of one occurrence times the number of trials ($600$ one minute trials).

Comment: what is the reciprocal of the event rate?

Comment: Sorry, it should be the event rate. You have $1800$ events in $600$ minutes, so the event rate would be $3$ per minute

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it:

Once you've found your $p_0 \ldots p_5$, you can treat them as probabilities of success in a Binomial distribution, e.g. the first one, $p_0 = e^{-3}, \ n=600$. The mean number of times you will observe this event is 
$$
m_0 = \sum_{k=0}^{600}k \binom{600}{k}p_0^k(1-p_0)^{600-k}=600 p_0=600 e^{-3}
$$
and son on. Do you understand now?

Comment: This looks like a justification for my Hint 2. (+1)

Comment: Yes, I saw it, and then thought how I would do it.